# Angularjs: check if debug has been enabled in $log decorator

Tags: angularjs

I created a decorator for $log in Angular. The $logProvider has the function debugEnabled, but from what I understand I only have access to the $log service. Is it possible to access the function 'debugEnabled()' of the $logProvider in a decorator somehow?

```
    $provide.decorator( '$log', [ "$delegate", function( $delegate ) {

        // Saving the original
        var _$log = (function( $delegate ) {
                return {
                    log   : $delegate.log,
                    info  : $delegate.info,
                    warn  : $delegate.warn,
                    debug : $delegate.debug,
                    error : $delegate.error
                };
            })( $delegate ),
        }]);
```

Comment: Is this the whole of your code? Unless I'm misunderstanding, this decorator doesn't add anything?

Comment: No it isn't, but I didn't post everything because I don't think it is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`debugEnabled()` is a method on the `$logProvider` itself. Remember that `$logProvider` is what is responsible for generating the `$log` service (via its `$get` function).

What decorators do is **intercept** the object that is **returned from `$get`** and allow you to add methods etc.

So to modify decorator behaviour based on whether debug is enabled, you simply need to inject `$logProvider` into your `.config` block and your decorator will have a closure over it:

```
angular.module('example', [])

.config( function ($provide, $logProvider){
  $provide.decorator('$log', function ( $delegate ){
    if ($logProvider.debugEnabled())
     // do something
    else 
     // do something else

    return $delegate;
  }
})
```